# Surface integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus

1) Find the area of the surface:

$Z= x^{2}-2y^{2} ,x^{2}+4y^{2}\leq 1$

my attempt :

$\int \int \sqrt{1+4x^{2}+16y^{2}}dxdy$

$\int \int \frac{r}{2}\sqrt{1+4r^{2}}$
=$\frac{\pi }{12} (5\sqrt{5}-1)$

Can someone verify if I  am correct ?

I need detailed solution because it is the first  problem in my problem set,if I understand it well I can figure out the rest by myself. the more detailed answer the better it is.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Use the formula
$$
\iint_D\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)^2}dA
$$
where
$D$ is the region contained within the ellipse $x^2+4y^2=1$.  In other words, with the integration order $dydx$, $x$ can vary between $-1$ and $1$, and by solving for $y$, we get that $y$ varies between $\pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{4}x^2}$.
$$
\int_{-1}^1\int_{-\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{4}x^2}}^{\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{4}x^2}}\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)^2}dydx.
$$
At this point, it might be best to use the substitution $2y=u$ so that the region of integration becomes a circle instead of an ellipse $(x^2+u^2=1)$.  Then, switch to polar.

Comment: Very elegant solution thanks , I have hard time to visualize the boundries of integration , you have any tip on how to get better at that ? I had problem with that also when dealing with tripple integrals .I could find the boundries in 2 D but not in 3 D . thanks again

Comment: The only way to get good at visualizing boundaries is to practice them more times than you think that you need to.  Also, just picking problems and finding all the ways to rewrite the integral makes things better.  If you want a more thorough answer, I suggest that you start a new question.

Comment: Thanks Ill do few more problems and see if there is a need to start new topic about that :)