# Surface integral of a function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Evaluate the integral 
$\iint_S\frac{x^{2}+y^{4}z}{x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}}dS$ 
where
$$S=\{(x,y,z)\;:\; x^{2}+y^{2}=1 ,-1\leq  z\leq 1\}.$$

Can someone please show me how to calculate this? 
And what is it am calculating, I am new on this topic.

I can do questions of this type : 
[Surface integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2033732/surface-integral/2033736#2033736)
But I don't even know what is it am calculating here.

I know I should parametrize my region $S$, it is a circular cylinder of radius $1$ and goes from $z=-1$ to $z =1$.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. Use the cylindrical coordinates with $dS=r d\theta dz$.

Here $r=1$, $x=\cos\theta$, $y=\sin \theta$.
Hence the integral can be written as
$$\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi} \int_{z=-1}^1 \frac{\cos^{2}(\theta)+\sin^{4}(\theta)z}{1+z^{2}} dz d\theta.$$
Note that since $S$ is symmetric with respect to the plane $z=0$, the term $\sin^{4}(\theta)z$ can be removed.

Comment: Thanks but it is still very unclear , i have 3 parameters when I should have only 2.

Comment: @Kasmir Khaan The parameters are two (it is a surface): $z$ and $\theta$. Note that $r$ is identically $1$.

Comment: Do you mean ,  r (z,$\theta $) = ( cos$\theta $, sin$\theta $ ,z ) ? 
according to the formula we are are given it should be of that form , then we take cross product to find dS )

Comment: @Kasmir Khaan Yes.

Comment: Thank you very much sir :)

Comment: when i did the partial derivative of r (z,$\theta $) i got (0,0,1 ) * ( sin$\theta $ , cos$\theta $,0 ) = rsin$\theta $ what is it am doing wrong here?
(* = cross pruduct)

Comment: Sorry never mind I found my mistake !

Comment: @Kasmir Khaan Look carefully here: http://www.southampton.ac.uk/~leor/soton/MATH1007/surfaces.pdf
At page 8, in the last example it is explained why the  area element is $dS=r d\theta dz$.